# Python: how to dynamically set function closure environment

Tags: python, compilation, global-variables, eval, dynamic-execution

I want to declare a function dynamically and I want to wrap any access to global variables *OR alternatively* define which variables are free and wrap any access to free variables.

I'm playing around with code like this:

```
class D:
    def __init__(self):
        self.d = {}     
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        print "D get", k
        return self.d[k]
    def __setitem__(self, k, v):
        print "D set", k, v
        self.d[k] = v
    def __getattr__(self, k):
        print "D attr", k
        raise AttributeError

globalsDict = D()

src = "def foo(): print x"

compiled = compile(src, "<foo>", "exec")
exec compiled in {}, globalsDict

f = globalsDict["foo"]
print(f)

f()
```

This produces the output:

```
D set foo <function foo at 0x10f47b758>
D get foo
<function foo at 0x10f47b758>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_eval.py", line 40, in <module>
    f()
  File "<foo>", line 1, in foo
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

What I want is somehow catch the access to `x` with my dict-like wrapper `D`. How can I do that?

I don't want to predefine all global variables (in this case `x`) because I want to be able to load them lazily.

Comment: Does it work if x is already in globalsDict?

Comment: @phkahler No, it doesn't. `f` still uses the real dict. The way around this is not to wrap `f`, but to wrap `x` in an object proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is **object proxying**.

Here is a recipe for an object proxy which supports pre- and post- call hooks:

http://code.activestate.com/recipes/366254-generic-proxy-object-with-beforeafter-method-hooks/

Create a subclass that doesn't actually load the object until the first time the `_pre` hook is called. Anything accessing the object will cause the real object to be loaded, and all calls will appear to be handled directly by the real object.

Comment: This still has the disadvantage that I have to create such an object proxy for every global variable which could possibly be accessed. This is already what I tried to avoid, to do any previous work; instead, I wanted to do it just all on-the-fly. (By e.g. wrapping the globals dict or so.)

Comment: Unfortunately, methods get called on the target, not the source. If you really don't have control over what `f` calls, your only option is to proxy for `x` in some way. If you have a lot of global variables that need to be loaded lazily, then your problem is probably that they should be in a class, where you can easily use descriptors / decorators / getters / setters / property to proxy for the former globals you've made into class or instance attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
class GlobalDict(object):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.d = kwargs

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        print 'getting', key
        return self.d[key]

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print 'setting', key, 'to', value
        if hasattr(value, '__globals__'):
            value.__globals__.update(self.d)
        self.d[key] = value
        for v in self.d.values():
            if v is not value:
                if hasattr(v, '__globals__'):
                    v.__globals__.update(self.d)

    def __delitem__(self, key):
        print 'deling', key
        del self.d[key]
        for v in self.d.values():
            if hasattr(v, '__globals__'):
                del v.__globals__[key]

>>> gd = GlobalDict()
>>> src = 'def foo(): print x'
>>> compiled = compile(src, '<foo>', 'exec')
>>> exec compiled in {}, gd
setting foo to <function foo at 0x102223b18>
>>> f = gd['foo']
getting foo
>>> f
<function foo at 0x102223b18>
>>> f() # This one will throw an error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<foo>", line 1, in foo
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
>>> gd['x'] = 1
setting x to 1
>>> f()
1
>>> del gd['x'] # removes 'x' from the globals of anything in gd
>>> f() # Will now fail again
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<foo>", line 1, in foo
NameError: global name 'x' is not defined
```

Comment: This is not really what I want. I want to *dynamically* catch the access. (This is because I want to dynamically load some of the variables lazily.)